# Is there a way to include all helper modules in RSpec configure block?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

My RSpec configure block looks something like this in my `spec_helper`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include Helpers
  config.include Helpers::CustomFinders
  config.include Helpers::SignUp
  ...
end
```

My helper file looks something like this:

```
module Helpers

  module CustomFinders
    # method defs here
  end

  module SignUp
    # method defs here
  end

  # Other modules here

  # Some other method defs here also
  ...
end
```

Is there a way to simply add ALL modules in the RSpec configure block in one line? I have a lot of modules in my helper file and will continue to have to add any new ones to my spec_helper.

Comment: For additional context, the helper methods are organized this way for re-usability of lengthier expectations and DRY-ing up specs. I'd welcome other approaches if there are better ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refactor your `Helpers` module to self-include all sub-modules, then in Rspec you only need to include the `Helpers` module

```
module Helpers
  def self.included(base)
    base.include CustomFinders
    base.include SignUp
  end

  module CustomFinders
    # method defs here
  end

  module SignUp
    # method defs here
  end

  # Other modules here

  # Some other method defs here also
end
```

In `spec_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include Helpers
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. I'll study up more on `self.included` from here.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if Helpers are found across a number of different files?